# Unable to toggle list items for a responsive nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to toggle the list view. What am I doing wrong?

html:

```
<nav>
    <span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <ul class="nav">
         <li>home</li>
         <li>about</li>
         <li>blog</li>
         <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {


    li {
        display: block;
        width: 480px;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    ul .nav{
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-btn:before {
        content: "Menu";
    }

    .nav-btn {
        display: block;
        background-color: yellow;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

script:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.nav-btn').on('click',
        function () {
            $('.nav').toggleClass('open');
        });
});
```

Is it possible to only do this with the help of javascript ?

Comment: where did you define the style for `.nav.open`? also note that you have an extra space between `ul` and `.nav`

Comment: Where do you have css for class "open"?

Comment: Hi! just that one space fixed the issue. But i am still not able to close the menu once I open it.

Comment: 1) ul .nav should be ul.nav(without space)
also add a new line with: ul.nav.active {display block:}

Answer (score 2):

First change `spacing` in below `style` i.e don't add space between them,

```
  ul.nav {
    display: none;
  }
```

Second use toggle and there is `no styling` declared for class `open` so add that and it works.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('.nav-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.nav').toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  li {
    display: block;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  ul.nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-btn:before {
    content: "Menu";
  }
  .nav-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.open{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <span class="nav-btn"></span>
  <ul class="nav">

    <li>home</li>

    <li>about</li>

    <li>blog</li>

    <li>contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the class 'open'. But there is no CSS for that.

Try this in CSS

```
.nav.open {
    display: block;
}
```